# How to read a song using an absolute location in AS3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash, audio, audio-player

I'm making a music player using AS3, but I'm having one problem; when I try to find a song outside the project folder using the AS3 script it simply doesn't work.

I've searched in the Internet and all the examples I've found used the relative location like this:

```
loadedSong = new Sound(new URLRequest("music.mp3"));
```

And it works for me, but with it I need always to have the songs in the root folder of the project. And I want to read them wherever they are without having to duplicate them to the root folder.

I tried to alter the code to use the absolute location like this:

```
loadedSong = new Sound(new URLRequest("c:\Users\pc\My Music\Artist\Album\music.mp3"));
```

But it fails with this error: "SecurityError: Error #2000: No active security context."

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try to use var loadedSong:Sound = new Sound(new URLRequest("c:/Users/pc/My Music/Artist/Album/music.mp3"));

Comment: You will need to use the 'filesystem' package for that, target desktop air for your app.

Comment: Because of Ilya Z and Timofei Davydik answers i could fix the problem.

My problem was I wasn't making it in AIR and the second part was the backslashes... I simply copied the file address using the Right-Click in the address bar of the explorer, but it copy with backslashes and flash uses frontslashes... Thank you two =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is security restriction of Flash Player. If you need a desktop player, you'd better use Adobe AIR. Otherwise, you can use web server and store files there. Or you can just add allow Flash Player to read from hard drive by adding trusted locations [here](http://www.macromedia.com/support/documentation/en/flashplayer/help/settings_manager04.html).